# Is it viable for each user to have their own account on an Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, security, credentials

I'm working on a system where users access an Oracle database through a Windows app. Each user has their own Oracle account, sometimes with multiple roles, and must provide credentials to Oracle through the application. It was implemented this way for security purposes. Is this a good practice?

Comment: I would say that it depend on your application and your requirements. Nowadays it is not common to do this, normally the security is controlled on a application layer. But it is not wrong to do it on the database, the main reason that I can think of is to not spend time creating that application security layer. Wheter it is a good pratice or not i don't really know. And if your application is returning the ´security errors´ to the users i would say that it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide user with Oracle credentials used by Windows application, he may as well connect to the database with another SQL client. It means that you must fully secure the application on database user level:

- Allow him to access and change only the data he is authorized to (on table, column and row level). Note this may require some complex logic, e.g. order status can be modified only for active customers.
- Remove unnecessary access to data dictionary views
- Remove unnecessary access to stored procedures and packages (lots of utility packages are granted to public by default!)

It is generally hard to identify all potential security issues and implement access control correctly without the help of a skilled DBA.

Comment: I think you've gotten this the wrong way around - when you create a user, by default it has zero privileges - you have to explicitly grant it access to the things it needs. Your points have more validity in cases where all users connect to the database using a single database account, which shifts the burden of security onto the application tier.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: Yes, after having a second thought you are abolutely right! For the reasons I wrote above you should rather set up individual accounts, a shared one will need to have too broad privileges. That's the case of a desktop app at least, which needs direct connection to db. Thanks for pointing it out :)